# Exclude Items in Iterator

Tags: php, iteration

I searching for a best practice in the Iterator interface of PHP.

Imagine I have a Menu with different Items. For each of the Items I can turn on or off the visibilty. Do you know a good place to place this filter? I thought about the [Iterator::rewind()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/iterator.rewind.php) Method to do a seperate loop but dislike the fact of looping through the items a second time.

I think I see the wood for the trees. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the abstrakt [FilterIterator](http://php.net/class.filteriterator) class. Would look something like

```
class MyFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
  public function accept () {
    $current = $this->current();
    // Test, if it is valid
    return $boolean;
  }
}

$iterator = new MyFilterIterator($myInnerIterator);
```

This way you also separate the menu from the filter, what makes it easier to replace the filter, if you want to change it.

Comment: I allready use a seperate Iterator. I'm a bit confused about needing a second Iterator iterating of the original MenuIterator. Anyway - it works great!

Comment: If you look at the file-iterators (especially if you want to iterate through them recursive), it may happen, that you need 4 or 5 iterators stacked together :D Of course, you dont _need_ it (in the meaning of the word), you can also squash everything into one, but its cleaner, if every class has its specific job and is not doing too much ("separation of concerns").

Comment: Yeah, your write. I though about it a while now and came to the simple solution that the MenuIterator extends the FilterIterator. So I can use the ArrayIterator constructed with the menu items to give it to the constructor of the FilterIterator. Like you said I also seperate the Iteration process into the MenuIterator and a extra RecursiveTreeIterator ... Iterator, Iterator, Iterator ... puh. It works great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Erm, can't you just use `continue` ?

```
$exclude=array(0,2,3,5);
$data=array('Item1','Item2','Item3','Item4','Item5','Item6');
foreach($data as $id=>$value){
   if(in_array($id,$exclude))continue;
   echo $value.' ';
}
```

Considering you have a visibility property you'd do something like `if(!visible)continue;`

Comment: Sure, I can. But this is why OOP is so usefull - putting everything where it belongs and be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Anyway - thanks for that!

Comment: If you really wanna do that I'd suggest going for the `next()` function not `rewind()`... but that's just me.

Comment: The question is about to filter specific items depending on an property of the item, not by a list of ids. Its possible with `foreach` too, but your solution is easier this way: `$toDisplay = array_diff(array_keys($data), $exclude)`;

Answer (score 0):

This iterator implementation will scann only visible items.
You can tune the class in order to parametrize the filter.

```
class myItem implements Iterator {

    private $position = -1;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = -1; // mean unknown position
    }

    function rewind() {
        $this->position = -1;
        $this->next();
    }

    function current() {
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        $p = $this->position+1;
        // skip invisible items
        while ( isset($this->array[$p]) && (!$this->array[$p]->visible)) $p++;
        $this->position = $p;
    }

    function valid() {
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}
```