# How to iterate a n-deep array to filter string nodes - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I iterate a multidimensional array and filter on string nodes?  I'm trying to create an easy way to sanitize data coming into my application via POST and think this would be really handy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude Items in Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593687/exclude-items-in-iterator)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreach with arrays within arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524227/php-foreach-with-arrays-within-arrays/5524267#5524267)

Comment: alternative http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php with FILTER_CALLBACK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to traverse the array and filter its string components.  For example:

```
function doFilter($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $arr[$Key] = sanitize($value);
        } else if (is_array($value)) {
            $arr[$key] = doFilter($value);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

function sanitize($str) {
    // Perform necessary steps to sanitize $str
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Recursion](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Fundamentals-of-Recursion-in-PHP/)

```
function sanitizePost($post) {
        if (is_array($post)){
            foreach ($post as $k => $p) {
                $post[$k] = sanitizePost($p);
            }
        } else {
            $post = sanatizeStringFunction($post); // may be use regex or something
        }

        return $post;
    }
```